# Detect multitouch (two fingers touch) on a sprite to apply pinch zoom behaviour

Tags: sprites, andengine, multitouch

I am using andengine, want to move, zoom and rotate multiple sprites individually on a scene. I have achieved "move" but for pinch zoom i am unable to get the event to two fingers' touch. Below is the code:

`public class Main extends SimpleBaseGameActivity` {

```
private Camera camera;
private BitmapTextureAtlas mBitmapTextureAtlas;
private ITextureRegion mFaceTextureRegion;
private ITextureRegion mFaceTextureRegion2;
Sprite face2;

private static final int CAMERA_WIDTH = 800;
private static final int CAMERA_HEIGHT = 480;

@Override
public EngineOptions onCreateEngineOptions() {
    camera = new Camera(0, 0, CAMERA_WIDTH, CAMERA_HEIGHT);
    EngineOptions engineOptions = new EngineOptions(true,
            ScreenOrientation.LANDSCAPE_FIXED, new RatioResolutionPolicy(
                    CAMERA_WIDTH, CAMERA_HEIGHT), camera);

    return engineOptions;
}

@Override
protected void onCreateResources() {
    BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.setAssetBasePath("gfx/");

    this.mBitmapTextureAtlas = new BitmapTextureAtlas(
            this.getTextureManager(), 1024, 1600, TextureOptions.NEAREST);
BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.createTiledFromAsset(this.mBitmapTextureAtlas,
    // this, "ui_ball_1.png", 0, 0, 1, 1),
    // this.getVertexBufferObjectManager());
    this.mFaceTextureRegion = BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory
            .createFromAsset(this.mBitmapTextureAtlas, this,
                    "ui_ball_1.png", 0, 0);
    this.mFaceTextureRegion2 = BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory
            .createFromAsset(this.mBitmapTextureAtlas, this,
                    "ui_ball_1.png", 0, 0);
    this.mBitmapTextureAtlas.load();
this.mEngine.getTextureManager().loadTexture(this.mBitmapTextureAtlas);

}

@Override
protected Scene onCreateScene() {

    this.mEngine.registerUpdateHandler(new FPSLogger());

    final Scene scene = new Scene();
    scene.setBackground(new Background(0.09804f, 0.6274f, 0.8784f));

    final float centerX = (CAMERA_WIDTH - this.mFaceTextureRegion
            .getWidth()) / 2;
    final float centerY = (CAMERA_HEIGHT - this.mFaceTextureRegion
            .getHeight()) / 2;

    final Sprite face = new Sprite(centerX, centerY,
            this.mFaceTextureRegion, this.getVertexBufferObjectManager()) {
        @Override
        public boolean onAreaTouched(final TouchEvent pSceneTouchEvent,
                final float pTouchAreaLocalX, final float pTouchAreaLocalY) {
            this.setPosition(pSceneTouchEvent.getX() - this.getWidth() / 2,
                    pSceneTouchEvent.getY() - this.getHeight() / 2);
            return true;
        }
    };
    face.setScale(2);
    scene.attachChild(face);
    scene.registerTouchArea(face);

     face2 = new Sprite(200, 200, this.mFaceTextureRegion2,
            this.getVertexBufferObjectManager()) {
        @Override
        public boolean onAreaTouched(final TouchEvent pSceneTouchEvent,
                final float pTouchAreaLocalX, final float pTouchAreaLocalY) {

            switch(pSceneTouchEvent.getAction()){
            case TouchEvent.ACTION_DOWN:


                int count = pSceneTouchEvent.getMotionEvent().getPointerCount() ;

                for(int i= 0; i <count; i++)
                {
                    int id = pSceneTouchEvent.getMotionEvent().getPointerId(i);
                }
                    break;
            case TouchEvent.ACTION_MOVE:

                        this.setPosition(pSceneTouchEvent.getX() -this.getWidth() / 2, pSceneTouchEvent.getY()-this.getHeight() / 2);

                    break;

            case TouchEvent.ACTION_UP:

                    break;

            }
            return true;
            }
        };

    face2.setScale(2);
    scene.attachChild(face2);
    scene.registerTouchArea(face2);

    scene.setTouchAreaBindingOnActionDownEnabled(true);
    return scene;
}
```

}

This line

```
int count = pSceneTouchEvent.getMotionEvent().getPointerCount() ;
```

should set **2** to the **count** variable if i touch the sprite with to fingers, then i can apply zooming functionality (setScale method) on the sprite by getting the distance between the coordinates of two fingers. Can anyone help me? **why it does not detect two fingers? and without this how can i zoom the sprite on pinch of two fingers**?

I am very new to game development, any help would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

add this code in `onCreateEngineOptions()`

```
final EngineOptions engineOptions = new EngineOptions(true, ScreenOrientation.LANDSCAPE_FIXED, new RatioResolutionPolicy(CAMERA_WIDTH, CAMERA_HEIGHT), this.mCamera);
        engineOptions.getTouchOptions().setNeedsMultiTouch(true);

        if(MultiTouch.isSupported(this)) {
            if(MultiTouch.isSupportedDistinct(this)) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "MultiTouch detected --> Both controls will work properly!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "MultiTouch detected, but your device has problems distinguishing between fingers.\n\nControls are placed at different vertical locations.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Sorry your device does NOT support MultiTouch!\n\n(Falling back to SingleTouch.)\n\nControls are placed at different vertical locations.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think first you have to look example provided by the AndEngine that is about pinch zoom functionality. Only this example is capable to provide enough guidance to achieve zoom in/out facility.

http://code.google.com/p/andengineexamples/source/browse/src/org/anddev/andengine/examples/PinchZoomExample.java

Also you have to add another extension for multi-touch support to you project.

https://github.com/nicolasgramlich

Above link contain information about all the andengine extension, you have to pick that you need.